# d3 table coming out of the div boundary

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Testing Table</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <style>
    #first {
      height: 50%;
      width: 80%;
      border: 3px solid #73AD21 !important;
      position: absolute !important;
    }
    tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
      background: #eee;
    }
    th {
      background: #333;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    td,
    th {
      padding: 6px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="first" viewBox="0 0 960 500" perserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function resize() {

      var w = document.getElementById('first').clientWidth;
      alert(w);
      var h = document.getElementById('first').clientHeight;
      alert(h);

      var first = $("#first"),
        aspect = first.width() / first.height(),
        first = first.parent();

      $(window).on("resize", function() {
        var targetWidth = first.width();
        first.attr("width", targetWidth);
        first.attr("height", Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
      }).trigger("resize");

      return {
        w: w,
        h: h
      };

    }

    function first() {

      var w = resize().w,
        h = resize().h;

      var data = [
        ["IP", "Count", "Action"],
        ["192.168.12.1", 20, "Allowed"],
        ["76.09.45.34", 40, "Blocked"],
        ["34.91.23.76", 80, "Allowed"],
        ["192.168.19.32", 16, "Blocked"],
        ["192.168.10.89", 50, "Blocked"],
        ["192.178.34.07", 18, "Allowed"],
        ["192.168.12.98", 30, "Blocked"],
        ["192.166.10.34", 12, "Blocked"],
        ["192.187.12.90", 97, "Allowed"],
        ["192.168.10.167", 21, "Blocked"]
      ];

      var dataHeader = data.slice(1, data.length);

      var titles = data[0];

      var table = d3.select('#first')
        .append("table")
        .attr("height", h)
        .attr("width", w)
        .style("border-collapse", 'collapse');

      var headers = table.append('thead')
        .append('tr')
        .selectAll('th')
        .data(titles)
        .enter()
        .append('th')
        .style("text-align", 'center')
        .text(function(d) {
          return d;
        });

      var rows = table.append('tbody')
        .selectAll('tr')
        .data(dataHeader)
        .enter()
        .append('tr');

      rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function(d) {
          return titles.map(function(k, i) {
            return {
              'value': d[i],
              'name': k
            };
          });
        })
        .enter()
        .append('td')
        .attr('data-th', function(d) {
          return d.name;
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.value;
        });

    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    first();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have successfully made the d3 table but I am unable to put the table into my div called "first". My div is getting responsive but not my table. My table is getting printed out of the div. I have even selected the d3.select("#first"), but still I am not getting. Am I missing something. Please help me in this. I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is inside the `<div>` however it is not restricted to the bounds.

To do this, use css.  Eg:

```css
    #first { overflow-y: auto }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Testing Table</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <style>
    #first {
      height: 50%;
      width: 80%;
      border: 3px solid #73AD21 !important;
      position: absolute !important;
    }
    tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
      background: #eee;
    }
    th {
      background: #333;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    td,
    th {
      padding: 6px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="first" viewBox="0 0 960 500" perserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function resize() {

      var w = document.getElementById('first').clientWidth;
      alert(w);
      var h = document.getElementById('first').clientHeight;
      alert(h);

      var first = $("#first"),
        aspect = first.width() / first.height(),
        first = first.parent();

      $(window).on("resize", function() {
        var targetWidth = first.width();
        first.attr("width", targetWidth);
        first.attr("height", Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
      }).trigger("resize");

      return {
        w: w,
        h: h
      };

    }

    function first() {

      var w = resize().w,
        h = resize().h;

      var data = [
        ["IP", "Count", "Action"],
        ["192.168.12.1", 20, "Allowed"],
        ["76.09.45.34", 40, "Blocked"],
        ["34.91.23.76", 80, "Allowed"],
        ["192.168.19.32", 16, "Blocked"],
        ["192.168.10.89", 50, "Blocked"],
        ["192.178.34.07", 18, "Allowed"],
        ["192.168.12.98", 30, "Blocked"],
        ["192.166.10.34", 12, "Blocked"],
        ["192.187.12.90", 97, "Allowed"],
        ["192.168.10.167", 21, "Blocked"]
      ];

      var dataHeader = data.slice(1, data.length);

      var titles = data[0];

      var table = d3.select('#first')
        .append("table")
        .attr("height", h)
        .attr("width", w)
        .style("border-collapse", 'collapse');

      var headers = table.append('thead')
        .append('tr')
        .selectAll('th')
        .data(titles)
        .enter()
        .append('th')
        .style("text-align", 'center')
        .text(function(d) {
          return d;
        });

      var rows = table.append('tbody')
        .selectAll('tr')
        .data(dataHeader)
        .enter()
        .append('tr');

      rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function(d) {
          return titles.map(function(k, i) {
            return {
              'value': d[i],
              'name': k
            };
          });
        })
        .enter()
        .append('td')
        .attr('data-th', function(d) {
          return d.name;
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.value;
        });

    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    first();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok I got it we can put a scroll bar in this table. But still the table is not getting responsive. The div

Comment: Again, this all needs to be sorted using CSS.  The d3 part is working correctly.

Comment: Ok I got it we can put a scroll bar in this table. But still the table is not getting responsive. The div is getting responsed as per my screen size but the table width and height remains fixed. How it can be? Please any suggestions.